# JSON loads in Safari but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox, safari

I'm trying to display the weather on a site I'm building using javascript and the worlweatheronline.com api. I could extract all the data I needed when testing in Safari, but in Firefox and Chrome nothing showed up. I was using the following code:

```
var url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Gent&'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Gent&
jQuery.get(url,function(r){
                        document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML +=  .... ; // do something
                    },"JSON");
```

I looked here on the forum and google for an alternative way to get the json data and came up with the following:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Gent&format=json&cc=yes&key=pjzd2w42md9qacscthr9gw4h',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(r) {
                            alert("test");
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("error");
                    }});
```

Again, Safari gives an alert containing "test" but both Firefox and Chrome display "error". When I look in the Web Console I see no errors, only a HTTP/1.1 200 OK message. I searched for hours but I can't find a solution... If somebody sees what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

BTW: JSONLint says the url is valid.

**EDIT:** Tried both dataType: 'json' and dataType: 'jasonp' but same results.

Comment: `dataType: 'jason'` ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that one: tried both dataType: 'jason' and dataType: 'jasonp'. Same results...

Comment: @OlivierCammaert Um, it's 'json' not 'jason'

Comment: @AndreiNemes um, obviously its referring to the dude thats getting the file. duh! :P

Comment: Can you ask Jason what's the response text he gets? (you can check this in the Network panel of your web inspector) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely barking at your query string. I would set it up a little more properly:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx',
    data:{q:'Gent',format:'json',cc:'yes',key:'pjzd2w42md9qacscthr9gw4h'},
    success:function(r){
        alert('success');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

By making your `data` as such, it should work alright. At least it'll be more readable and extensible.

Comment: Thank you so much! using data:{q:'Gent', ...} did the job!

Comment: no worries! for future reference, i recommend using the `data:{key:'value'}` pairing over a query string every time. much cleaner and more maintainable.